# While loop for multiple array in python causing truth value error

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I get while count < max_iteration:ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() with the code that I have written, cant seem to find the error and not sure why the error appears. Can anyone help me with this ? Much appreciate the help in advance.

```
def iteration_calculation(corroded_wall_thickness,
                          external_radius_mm,
                          lambda_value,
                          youngs_modulus_mpa,
                          poissons_ratio,
                          max_iteration,
                          epsilon_convergence_value):
    list_value = {}
    count = 0
    min_value = float("inf")
    last_value = float("inf")
    changed_n_value = 2
    while count < max_iteration:
        new_value = elastic_buckling_pressure(corroded_wall_thickness=corroded_wall_thickness,
                                              external_radius_mm=external_radius_mm,
                                              lambda_value=lambda_value,
                                              n_value=changed_n_value,
                                              youngs_modulus_mpa=youngs_modulus_mpa,
                                              poissons_ratio=poissons_ratio)
        list_value[changed_n_value] = new_value
        if abs(last_value - new_value) < epsilon_convergence_value:
            break
        last_value = new_value
        if new_value < min_value:
            min_value = new_value
            min_key =changed_n_value
        changed_n_value += 0.10
        count += 1

    return min_value, min_key, list_value
```

I am using the code below as training data:

```
def test_iteration_calculation():
    args = {'corroded_wall_thickness': np.array([10, 10]),
            'external_radius_mm': np.array([250, 250]),
            'lambda_value': np.array([0.5, 0.5]),
            'youngs_modulus_mpa': np.array([350000, 350000]),
            'poissons_ratio': np.array([0.33, 0.33]),
            'max_iteration': np.array([10000, 10000]),
            'epsilon_convergence_value': np.array([1, 1])

            }
    output1, output2, output3 = np.array(list(itertools.starmap(rb_value_selector_function,
                                                              list(zip(iteration_calculation(**args))))))
```

Comment: `max_iteration` is a `numpy.array`. `count` is an integer. So `count < max_iteration` is a `numpy.array`, you can't have a `numpy.array` as a condition for a `while` loop (unless it has a single element), because it is undefined under what circumstances such an array is `True` or `False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the condition for your `while` loop, you use `<` to compare an integer `count` to a `numpy.array`. The result of this is another `numpy.array` of boolean values. E.g.

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> count = 9
>>> max_iteration = array([10, 10])
>>> count < max_iteration
array([ True,  True])
```

The `while` loop needs to decide whether to continue by testing whether that condition is `True`. Is it? Try to convert the expression to a boolean to find out.

```
>>> bool(count < max_iteration)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Which is the error you get in your code at the `while` loop.

To fix it, it depends what you want to do. I don't understand what you are doing with your code, so I cannot say for sure, but there are a couple of possibilities:

**`max_iteration` should really be a scalar**

Because you are using it to count iterations in a loop, and you compare it to an `int` `count` anyway. The quick fix for this is to change your `while` condition to `count < max_iteration[0]`, which compares the first element of the array to `count`.

But if you are going to use only the first element of the array, there is really no point in it being an array. So instead of giving a `numpy.array` as an argument to your `iteration_calculation` function, give an `int`.

**Use `a.any` or `a.all`**

As the error message suggests, you can use the methods `any` or `all` to convert the array of booleans to a single `True` or `False`. E.g.

```
while (count < max_iteration).any():
```

or

```
while (count < max_iteration).all():
```

again, which to choose depends on what you are actually trying to do with your algorithm, which isn't clear to me from the question. Docs are available for [`any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html#numpy.ndarray.any) and [`all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html#numpy.ndarray.all) to help you decide.

Comment: I passed the conditions as scalar values: hard coding ``` max_iteration = 10000
    epsilon_convergence_value = 0.01``` inside the code however this still causes issues, because of the if condition that follows

Comment: I have a feeling that is just the same problem with different variable names. E.g. does `elastic_buckling_pressure` return an `array` or a scalar value?

Answer (score 0):

You are entering the `max_iteration` value as an array and then comparing an `int` count with it.You might want to do something like this, I'm not sure which dimension you want, but since both are same so:

```
while count < max_iteration[0]
```

Comment: This is almost certainly not what the OP wants, because it compares the length of the first dimension of `max_iteration` with `count`. More likely `max_iteration[0]` is wanted.

Comment: @L.Grozinger my bad, made an edit accordingly

Comment: @L.Grozinger Thanks